# Replace string in between forward slash

Tags: php

I want to replace string thike this.

My string is

```
echo "/mytest/";
```

I want to replace "mytest" to website this

```
echo "/website/";
```

How can i do this /

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function:

```
echo str_replace('mytest', 'website', '/mytest/');
```

Answer (score 0):

basic form

```
$string='/path/to/mytest/page.ext';
echo preg_replace('@(mytest)@','website',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **str_replace()** function to replace a spacified word from a string.

**Examples:**

```
$str="Can you please replaceMe ?";
echo str_replace("replaceMe","keep me",$str);
```

**output :** Can you please keep me?

**2)example**

```
$mystr="my string is mytest";
echo str_replace("mytest","mywebsite",$mystr);
```

**output:** my string is mywebsite